# A fscanf is making a error in a if condition

Tags: c

I have a problem in one function. In there I open a .txt (which opens right, and I start to save the variables until an if. it enters in the condition and then it doesn't do the sfanf.
The program can build and run until it passes this function.
It says problem is in comments above the fscanf where the error is.
The previous code is all working as it should.

```
ppac le_pacientes(char *nomefich){
ppac lipac=NULL,novo,aux=lipac;
pac pacientes;
FILE *f;

f=fopen(nomefich,"rt");
if(!f){
    printf("Erro ao abrir ficheiro\n");
    return NULL;
}

pacientes.prox=NULL;

while(fscanf(f,"%100[^\n]",pacientes.nome)==1){    
    fscanf(f,"%d-%d-%d",&pacientes.dn,&pacientes.mn,&pacientes.an);
    
    
    pacientes.idade = verifica_idade(lipac);
    
    fscanf(f,"%d consultas",&pacientes.nconsult);
    if(pacientes.nconsult>=2)
    {
        ///  !!!!problem!!!!  ///
        fscanf(f,"%s",pacientes.tipoc1);printf("hello\n\n");
        //fscanf(f,"%d/%d/%d -",&pacientes.dc1,
               // &pacientes.mc1,&pacientes.ac1);
        //fscanf(f," %100[^\n]",pacientes.nomemed1);
        
        //fscanf(f,"%s - %d/%d/%d - ",pacientes.tipoc2,&pacientes.dc2,
                //&pacientes.mc2,&pacientes.ac2);
        //fscanf(f," %100[^\n]",pacientes.nomemed2);
    }
    /*else if(pacientes.nconsult==1)
    {
        fscanf(f,"%c - %d/%d/%d - ",pacientes.tipoc1,&pacientes.dc1,
                &pacientes.mc1,&pacientes.ac1);
        fscanf(f," %100[^\n]",pacientes.nomemed1);
    }*/
    printf("hello\n\n");
    novo=malloc(sizeof(pac));
    if(!novo){
        printf("ERRO a alocar memoria\n");
        fclose(f);
        return lipac;
    }
    
    *novo=pacientes;
    if(!lipac)
        lipac=novo;
    else
        aux->prox=novo;
    aux=novo; 
}

return lipac;
```

Comment: Use `fgets()` instead of `fscanf(f, "%100[^\n]", pacientes.nome)` do `while (fgets(f, pacientes.nome, 100) != NULL)`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi, the problem is inside the if, cause above the if everythink is workin ok, but inside the if it isn't doing the fscanf

Comment: How do you know that it isn't? why are you ignoring the return value of `fscanf()`?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I've tried as soon as you last posted what you've sad and it's the same

And with printf I've tested where the error was coming from

Comment: It looks to me like your loop never skips over the newline at the end of the lines. So when it gets to the top of the loop, it will read a zero-length string into `pacientes.nome`.

Comment: Replacing `fgets()` will not fix your problem, it's not clear what your problem is. But `fscanf(f, "%100[^\n]" ...)` as a clear abuse of `fscanf()` and there exists `fgets()`. Also, you can use the length of the array in `fgets()` dynamically, whereas in `fscanf()` it has to be hard-coded in the format string.

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? What is in the file?